# Switching between Python 3.5 and 3.6 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, python, python3

I seek to be able to type something like

```
python36
```

or:

```
python35
```

in the command prompt to be be able to run 3.6 or 3.5 shells, respectively. When I type python in the command prompt, it only opens a 3.5 shell, and if I try to specify 3.6 by typing `python3.6` or `python3.5` or `python36` or `python35`, it doesn't recognize the commands. For both installations, I checked the "Add to my path" box, and have since tried to manually add them to my path using system settings/advanced/environment variables, etc, but it's not clear to me how to best do this.

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: How you modify the system and user variables on Windows is well documented what step are you stuck on, edit your question, be specific

Answer (score 5):

Call `py.exe` instead of `python`:

- `py -3.6` will open a 3.6 shell;
- `py -3.5` will open a 3.5 shell;
- `py` (check the version of an open shell: it could depend on installation and further settings).

**Source**: **[Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)**

> *New in version 3.3.*
>
> The Python launcher for Windows is a utility which aids in locating
>   and executing of different Python versions. It allows scripts (or the
>   command-line) to indicate a preference for a specific Python version,
>   and will locate and execute that version.
>
> Unlike the `PATH` variable, the launcher will correctly select the
>   most appropriate version of Python. It will prefer per-user
>   installations over system-wide ones, and orders by language version
>   rather than using the most recently installed version.